# App Engine - Java: Chain Multiple MapReduce Jobs?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore

I know how to start a `MapReduceJob` like: `MapReduceJob.start()` but,

How can I chain multiple `MapReduceJob`s together so that the output of the last reducer can be used by the next one's mapper ?

Answer (score 0):

Using AE pipelines. Look at this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/blob/master/java/example/src/com/google/appengine/demos/mapreduce/entitycount/ChainedMapReduceJob.java#L89).